# Pygame masks Python

Tags: python, pygame

So was learning how to make a game with pygame in a tutorial and that game needed collision so they created pygame masks object but i did not get why to check the collision between two objects we need to find the distance between there x and y coordinate can someone explain me why we need the x and y coordinates distance between the two objects

Here is the code collision function:

```
def collide(obj1, obj2):
    offset_x = obj2.x - obj1.x
    offset_y = obj2.y - obj1.y
    return obj1.mask.overlap(obj2.mask, (offset_x, offset_y)) != None # (x, y) it will return if collison else false
```

Can anyone explain me the logic how the mask system in pygame works and why we need `offset_x`, `offset_y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mask is created from an image. The masks are just a grid with Boolean values. One field in the mask corresponds to one pixel in the surface. If it is `True`, the pixel in the corresponding image belongs to the colored sprite. If `False`, the pixel in the corresponding image belongs to the background. A [`pygame.mask.Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) object has no position.
The [`pygame.mask.Mask.overlap`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask) method checks whether the objects overlap when they are placed on the screen. Since the objects will not be placed exactly in the same place, you need to specify the offset. See [PyGame collision with masks is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455811/pygame-collision-with-masks-is-not-working/57499484#57499484) and [Collision between masks in PyGame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55817422/collision-between-masks-in-pygame/55818093#55818093).

```
+---------------+
| mask 1   .    |
|         oy    |
|          .    |
|... ox ...+-------------+
|          |    |        |
|          |    |        |
+----------|----+        |
           |             |
           | mask 2      |
           +-------------+
```

`ox` is `offset_x`
`oy` is `offset_y`

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SurfaceMaskIntersect](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SurfaceMaskIntersect#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

See also: [Mask](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_mask.md)

---

When you use [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) objects, you don't need to compute the offset. You can us [`pygame.sprite.collide_mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask), which computes the offsets from the `.rect` attrbutes. See [How can I made a collision mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043600/how-can-i-made-a-collision-mask/56045037#56045037) and [Pygame mask collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077813/pygame-mask-collision/60078039#60078039)

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SpriteMask](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SpriteMask#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

See also [Sprite mask](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_sprite_and_sprite_mask.md#sprite-mask)